# Django Как присвоить id из Модели User к другую модель

Tags: python, django

Столкнулся с проблемой что id модели User не присваиваться через ForeignKey к другой модели.
Через это поле должны выводиться страницы дневника пользователя.
Естественно что id должен присваивается автоматически

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Page_Dairy(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
   text = models.TextField()
   data = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)
   author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True ,blank=True)



   def __str__(self):
       return self.title
```

forms.py

```
from urllib import request
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django import forms 
from .models import *

class LoginUser(AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(label='Логин',widget=forms.TextInput())
    password = forms.CharField(label='Пароль',widget=forms.PasswordInput())

class CreatePage(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Page_Dairy
        fields = ['title', 'text']
        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput,
            'text' : forms.Textarea,
        }
```

Comment: у тебя в author должен падать id юзера

Comment: Но он не присваивается , приходиться в ручную это делать